# Why my action is not triggering in the reducer?

Tags: reactjs, redux

does anyone knows why nothing happens when the button is clicked?

im trying to fetch the movielist from the server when the button is clicked but it doesnt even shows that the action is working the way i expected to be.

my react index js

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { getMovies } from '../../actions/movieActions';

const Home = ({ movie }) => {
  const handleClick = () => {
    getMovies();
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => handleClick()}>Get Movies</button>
    </div>
  );
};

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  movie: state.movie.movies
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { getMovies })(Home);
```

my rootReducer

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import movieReducer from './movieReducer';

export default combineReducers({
  movie: movieReducer
  // log is what we are calling our state
});
```

my movie reducer

```
import { GET_MOVIES } from '../actions/types';

const initialState = {
  movies: null
};

export default (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case GET_MOVIES:
      return {
        ...state,
        movies: action.payload
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

my movie actions

```
import { GET_MOVIES } from './types';

// get movies from server
export const getMovies = () => async dispatch => {
  try {
    const res = await fetch('http://localhost:5000/api/movies');
    const data = await res.json();

    dispatch({
      type: GET_MOVIES,
      payload: data
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};
```

my types.js

```
export const GET_MOVIES = 'GET_MOVIES';
```

my store.js

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import { composeWithDevTools } from 'redux-devtools-extension';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';

import rootReducer from './reducers';

const initialState = {};

const middleware = [thunk];

const store = createStore(
  rootReducer,
  initialState,
  composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(...middleware))
);

export default store;
```

Comment: Change `export const getMovies = () => async dispatch => {` to `export const getMovies = async dispatch => {`

Comment: @technophyle doesnt work that way, redux thunk let you return a function within a function. its the same as writing export const getMovies = () => {
  return async(dispatch) => {
    ...
  }
}

Comment: Ah you're right. I added the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your error is in calling the action directly, instead of the `connect`ed `getMovies` prop here:

```
const handleClick = () => {
  getMovies();
};
```

Should be:

```
const handleClick = () => {
  this.props.getMovies();
};
```